# How to find difference between two tables in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I have got two tables 'Customer'.

The first one:

```
ID | UserID | Date 
1. |   1    | 2018-05-01
2. |   1    | 2018-05-02
```

The second one:

```
ID | UserID | Date 
1. |   1    | 2018-05-01
2. |   1    | 2018-05-02
3. |   1    | 2018-05-03
```

So, as you can see in the second table, there is one row more. 
I have written so far this code:

```
;with cte_table1 as (
select UserID, count(id) cnt from db1.Customer group by UserID
),
cte_table2 as (
select UserID, count(id) cnt from db2.Customer group by UserID
)
select * from cte_table1 t1
join cte_table2 t2 on t2.UserID = t1.UserID
where t1.cnt <> t2.cnt
```

and this gives me expected result:

```
UserID | cnt | UserID | cnt
   1   |  2  |   1    |  3
```

And so far, everything is fine. The thing is, these two tables have many rows and I'd like to have result with dates, where cnt does not match.

In other words, I'd like to have something like this:

```
    UserID | cnt |     Date    | UserID | cnt |    Date
       1   |  2  | 2018-05-01  |  1     |  3  | 2018-05-01
       1   |  2  | 2018-05-02  |  1     |  3  | 2018-05-01
       1   |  2  |    NULL     |  1     |  3  | 2018-05-03
```

The best soulution would be resultset where both cte's are joined to give this:

```
    UserID | cnt |     Date    | UserID | cnt |    Date
       1   |  2  | 2018-05-01  |  1     |  3  | 2018-05-01
       1   |  2  | 2018-05-02  |  1     |  3  | 2018-05-01
       1   |  2  |    NULL     |  1     |  3  | 2018-05-03
       1   |  2  | 2018-05-30  |  1     |  3  | NULL
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `EXCEPT`

Comment: perhaps what you want is `FULL OUTER JOIN` ?

Comment: maybe, but how to add dates to result? I've stuck and no idea how to go further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a **[FULL OUTER JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx)** query like below

```
Select 
  C1.UserID,
  C1.cnt,
  C1.Date,
  C2.UserID,
  C2.cnt,
  C2.Date
from
db1.Customer C1
FULL OUTER JOIN
db2.Customer C2
on C1.UserId=C2.UserId and C1.date=C2.Date
```

Comment: It does not work, but thank you anyway. I did it myself.